# bounded continuous function are open in set of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $D$ be a metric space and $K \subset D$ a compact set. Let $C_b(K) = \{ f \in C(K, \mathbb{R}) | \mbox{ f is continuous and bounded } \}$.
I want to prove that $C_b(K)$ and B(K,1) := $\{ f \in C_b(K) : |f(x)| \leq 1 \forall x \in K \} $ is separable.

I know already that: If $K$ is a compact metrizable space then $C(K, \mathbb{R})$ is separable (a consequence of stone weierstrass).

Define the topology on $C(K, \mathbb{R})$  de topology generated by $B_{d_K}(f,\epsilon)$ with $d_K(f,g) = \sup(d(f(x),g(x))$ (this is a pseudometric) . 
But proving that $B(K,1)$  is separable , is a problem for me because i would think that  $B(K,1)$   is closed in $C_b(K)$ but we don’t have the property that a closed subspace of a separable  subspace is separable .

So can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I have corrected it

Comment: Your pseudometric is in fact a metric. For metric spaces, every subspace of a separable space is separable.

Comment: How do you know that a subspace of a separable space is separable (in a common topology, this holds only for open subspaces)